# How can I add Hindi content in ionic app development?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, internationalization

I am developing an android and ios app using ionic framework and it is in Hindi language content and that's why I am not able to add Hindi content right now. Anybody have a solution regarding this one, on how to make it  possible.?

Comment: Try and paste code content. Ionic framework version.  You know it helps to understand a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a language.js file in your main->constants folder and add the contents for translation like this:

```
'use strict';
(function () {
 angular.module('main')
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, 
$translateProvider) {
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
welcome_message: 'Welocome',
hello_message: 'Hello',
mobile_message: 'Mobile number',
});
$translateProvider.translations('hi', {
welcome_message: 'स्वागत हे',
hello_message: 'नमस्ते',
mobile_message: 'मोबाइल नंबर',
});
if (window.localStorage['language'] === undefined) {
window.localStorage['language'] = 'hi';
}
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage(window.localStorage['language']);
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('hi');
});
})();
```

In your html file you can use translate like

```
<label class="item item-input InputFormFull">
      <span class="input-label">{{'mobile_message' | translate}} * </span>
       <input type="tel">
    </label>
```

You have install a translate plugin which you can install from the following link: [translatelink](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)

```
npm install --save-dev angular-translate
```

And in main.js you have to include the dependency if your are using hindi for entire app:

```
angular.module('main', [
'ionic',
'ngCordova',
'ui.router',
'ion-place-tools',
'pascalprecht.translate',
])
```

Comment: you can do any number of language inside the language.js itself but you should have the relevant Sanskrit strings for it.

Comment: And relevant string possible for it? If yes then how?

Comment: you can add a new translater.provider in language.js like sk for sanskrit and add the strings and if u want the sanskrit to be default language then change the $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('hi');  to  $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('sk');

Comment: I have krutiDev font and also content with it then? Is it possible ?

Comment: Just check it out but your phone should support the sanskrit also i think fon t is not needed bcoz if your downloading any contents in sanskrit language means then at that time it is needed.

Comment: Okay let's I develop above things if it will be working then fine